# ESLint options - overrideConfig not loading

Tags: node.js, eslint, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I installed ESLint and set these settings in setting.json but EsLint does not start properly globally for VS Code.

```
Invalid Options: - Unknown options: envs, globals, parserOptions, rules
 - 'envs' has been removed. Please use the 'overrideConfig.env' option instead.
 - 'globals' has been removed. Please use the 'overrideConfig.globals' option instead.
 - 'parserOptions' has been removed. Please use the 'overrideConfig.parserOptions' option instead. 
 - 'rules' has been removed. Please use the 'overrideConfig.rules' option instead.
```

These are my settings:

```
"eslint.options": {
        "envs": [
            "es6",
            "browser",
            "node",
            "mocha"
        ],
        "globals": [
            "expect"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 2019,
            "sourceType": "module",
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "jsx": true
            }
        },
        "rules": {
            "semi": "error",
            "curly": "error",
            "quotes": [
                "warn",
                "single"
            ],
            "no-undef": "error"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still looking for an answer, I just had the same issue.. You need to wrap your eslint options into an `overrideConfig` object. In this case the aimed object in the error message `overrideConfig.(...)` will be provided correctly.
Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70378398/12873715)