# ESLint: Invalid Options when create-next-app

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, next.js, eslint

I'm creating a new Next.js application.
When i run `yarn create-next-app` and i start to write javascript code inside Visual Studio Code, the ESlint extension throw back an error every time i digit.
And, naturally, eslint doesn't work.

The error is:

```
ESLint: Invalid Options: - Unknown options: env, parserOptions, rules - 'parserOptions' has been removed. Please use the 'overrideConfig.parserOptions' option instead. - 'rules' has been removed. Please use the 'overrideConfig.rules' option instead.. Please see the 'ESLint' output channel for details.
```

This is the image for an immediate visual recognizing:

[Eslint extension error on Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uygac.png)

This is my `package.json` file (the default package.json given by Next.js):

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7"
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 19):

Solved on my own by wrapping the content of `esling.options` into `overrideConfig` in my **settings.json** vscode file, like this:

```
"eslint.options": {
    "overrideConfig": {
      "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
      },
      "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2019,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true
        }
      },
      "rules": {
        "no-debugger": "off"
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

This may be obvious to most, but I wanted to add one caveat. The above config fix works, but make sure you do it at the user level as well as the workspace level. If the eslint.options json doesn't have the overrideConfig at the user level config it will continue to error. Sorry if this is obvious, but I just spent the last hour trying to understand why I was continuing to get the invalid options error despite adding the above solution until I realized I was making the change in the workspace only. Hopefully this can save someone a headache.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the exact cause of the problem, but I was able to fix the issue by completely reinstalling vscode. Use this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#:%7E:text=the%20.zip%20contents.-,macOS,and%20select%20Move%20to%20Trash.) to do a clean uninstall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).