# Problem with ESLint after installing npm create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, package.json

ESLint: Invalid Options: - Unknown options: env, parserOptions, rules - 'parserOptions' has been removed. Please use the 'overrideConfig.parserOptions' option instead. - 'rules' has been removed. Please use the 'overrideConfig.rules' option instead.. Please see the 'ESLint' output channel for details.

My package.json is :
[package.json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B28Fk.png)

Comment: Please include any code in your question as text rather than screenshots - screen readers and search engines can't read text in screenshots. Also, as this looks like an ESLint issue, please add the content of any .eslintrc.json files and any messages in the ESLint output window to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did not run into such problem personally but kind of solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377900/eslint-invalid-options-when-create-next-app).

Anyway I would recommend to check that you have some fresh 14+ version on NodeJS installed (because `create-react-app 5` [dropped support of Node 10 and 12](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#creating-an-app)) and also that your IDE and it's `ESLint` plugin are up-to-date.